# SQL Server : triggers to fire

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE table1;
CREATE table2;

CREATE trigger1 ON table1 AFTER DELETE AS DELETE FROM table1;
CREATE trigger2 ON table1 AFTER DELETE AS DELETE FROM table2;

DELETE FROM table1
```

Last query will fire `trigger1` and `trigger2`.

Whether `trigger1` fires `trigger2` again (if database default options are set)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the option RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS is set to on and the configuration "nested triggers" is set to 1 then then yes firing trigger1 will cause both trigger1 and trigger2 to fire again and then again etc up to 32 levels deep for after triggers.  Otherwise no they won't fire recursively.

Comment: I was confused because the first is recursive trigger and the second is not

Comment: The default options are - recursive triggers are set OFF and nested triggers are set ON... What will be in that case?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the second trigger is not recursive.  Each time the delete on table1 is run both triggers will fire.  If I understand things correctly with recursive triggers set to OFF and nested triggers to ON it should NOT recurse.  But I would write a test if I was you.  Make trigger2 an insert into table2 instead of a delete so you can see how many times it fired.

Comment: I tested and it actualy fires second trigger. Posting here I just wanted to know how it should be because first trigger use temporary table to delete values in self table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  Are you wondering why the second trigger is being fired over and over again?  If so that's fairly easy.  You delete from the table, that fires trigger1 which deletes from the table causing a recursive loop right?  Well also each time you delete from the table trigger2 is fired.  So trigger2 will fire once for each time you delete from table1, or once for each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the `nested triggers` setting on the server. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx